# How to invoke DatePicker from Mantine UI on click of a button/ div?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, mantine

So I am using Mantine DatePicker for a project.

I have to apply UI as follows:

[image: Required UI]

Here the user can select either of the check-in or check-out date and the date picker will appear.

Unfortunately, the default UI picker is as follows from Mantine.

[image: Default UI]

How can I change the default UI to look like the required UI?

The possible solution I can think of is that when someone clicks on either the check-in date or checkout date, the date picker modal will appear. But I don't know how this works.

```
import { DatePickerInput } from "@mantine/dates";

<DatePickerInput
      type="range"
      valueFormat="DD MMM, YY"
      value={value}
      onChange={setValue}
      numberOfColumns={2}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      styles={{
        day: {
          "&[data-selected], &[data-selected]:hover": {
            backgroundColor: `#000000}`,
            color: "white",
          },

          "&[data-in-range], &[data-in-range]:hover": {
            backgroundColor: `#000000`,
            color: "white",
            opacity: "0.5",
          },

          "&[data-first-in-range], &[data-first-in-range]:hover": {
            backgroundColor: `#000000`,
            color: "white",
            opacity: "1",
          },

          "&[data-last-in-range], &[data-last-in-range]:hover": {
            backgroundColor: `#000000`,
            color: "white",
            opacity: "1",
          },
        },
        input: {
          "&:focus": {
            borderColor: "#000000",
          },
        },
      }}
    />
```

Comment: can you provide some code, please?

Comment: @Hatana code added